# Apache MiNiFi compatibility with jre-1.7

Tags: java, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I am working on integration of Minifi and Nifi.currently i am working with Minifi version-0.1.0(java - 1.8).I tried working with Minifi 0.1.0 in a server which has java-1.7.But when i tried running any minifi commands like:
    bin/minifi.sh status. 
    But getting this error:
    Java home: /usr/local/java/default
    MiNiFi home: /opt/minifi-0.0.1

```
Bootstrap Config File: /opt/minifi-0.0.1/conf/bootstrap.conf

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/nifi/minifi/bootstrap/RunMiNiFi : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I think by default Minifi has been configured to run with Java-1.8

So i also tried with Minifi(version-0.0.1),facing same issues.
I want to know which minifi version is compatible with jre-1.7.

I would be grateful for any answers.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to upgrade your Java to 1.8 and will fix your problems

Answer (score 0):

Initial development on Apache MiNiFi was started in 2016, at which time Java 1.7 was over four years old and Java 1.8 had been released for ~2 years. As Apache NiFi 1.0.0 and following versions removed backward compatibility with Java 7 in August 2016, the foundation for MiNiFi Java 0.0.1 was not designed to have Java 7 compatibility. There is no version of MiNiFi which was developed to be compatible with Java 7.